# Why can't I drop files on to Eclipse / SWT Drop Target from a CD in windows

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, drag-and-drop, swt

In my Eclipse RCP application I have a TreeViewer that is a drop target for files, it works fine in most circumstances, however when I try and drag files stored on a CD ROM from windows explorer to the node the icon that indicates drops are allowed doesn't change and dropping does nothing.

Since people seemed confused about my question here's a more detailed explanation:

When executing the code below (supplied by Baz), I am able to drag files and drop them on to the text box, when I drag a file from most locations on my machine, the window appears like this ->

[image: Working Drag]

The cursor indicates that I can drop, and when I release the mouse the `drop(DropTargetEvent event)` method is invoked.

Now when I do the same thing, but take a file from explorer that is on a DVD in my optical drive then it looks like this:

[image]

Indicating that the drop is not allowed, and when I release the mouse the `drop(DropTargetEvent event)` method is NOT invoked.

It's also worth noting that I am able to drop the same DVD files in to a folder in the eclipse navigator, indicating that this isn't a machine specific issue, there must be something different in the eclipse trees that allows it but I can't see it.

```
package widgets;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DND;
import org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget;
import org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTargetAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.dnd.FileTransfer;
import org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Transfer;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.PluginTransfer;

public class SourceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));

        final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

        DropTarget dt = new DropTarget(text, DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_LINK);
        dt.setTransfer(new Transfer[] { FileTransfer.getInstance(), PluginTransfer.getInstance() });
        dt.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
            public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
                String fileList[] = null;
                FileTransfer ft = FileTransfer.getInstance();
                if (ft.isSupportedType(event.currentDataType)) {
                    fileList = (String[]) event.data;
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileList));
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(300, 100);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check if the `transferType` within the `validateDrop` method differs from the one when dropping from the HDD?

Comment: They are TransferData objects that don't seem to have any major differences in structure, but the operation seems to always be 16 for the ROM files whereas for the files that work the operations changes to 2 when over a node and 16 when not, which suggests to me that the node isn't registering as a viable target for what is being dragged. It's strange that a call to validateDrop is made even though it has no intention of actually allowing you to perform it.

Comment: Based on the name `**validate**Drop()` it makes sense. Will research a bit. Maybe I'll find a solution.

Comment: The name makes it sound like it should be dropped, but in this situation even though it's returning true the framework won't try and perform the drop because it's already decided that the target is invalid. Thanks for your time in advance Baz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that not all of the DND operations possible are supported when coming from a CDROM device.  Therefore you need to implement a couple of more methods on the `DropTargetAdapter` in order to modify the Drop operation while in progress to narrow down the operations that will actually be performed so that the OS doesn't prevent the drop.

I took your example and just made the small change to the `DropTargetAdapter`

```
    @Override
    public void dropAccept( DropTargetEvent event )
    {
        Object object = FileTransfer.getInstance().nativeToJava( event.currentDataType );
        if( object instanceof String[] )
        {
            String[] strs = (String[]) object;
            System.out.println("dropAccept " + strs[0]);
            event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY;
        }
        event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY;
    }
    @Override
    public void dragEnter( DropTargetEvent event )
    {
        event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY;
    }
```

Comment: That is some fine work there my good fellow. So essentially overriding the detail to always appear as if it's a copy? Will this not cause strange behaviour for other event types?

Comment: So you can add some code to be more selective of when you "modify" this event.  I'll add some code to my answer that shows how you can "sniff" the location of what is about to be dropped and do some determination when to modify and when to leave alone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find the equivalent in the eclipse trees as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think updated your question clarifies what problem is.

Your Drop Target used `DND_MOVE` as Flag.
Since we can't remove files in Read Only Medias such as DVD,

Sender(in this case, OS's shell) will refuse DND communication no matter whether receiver's decision is.

Screen shot of yours shows **Moving** DND Feedback not **Copy**.

`dropAccept()` gives you last chance to modify communication request,
Use this carefully, because multiple drop target listeners per each Transfer Type can be exist. To support this case, TreeViewer's DND APIs are slightly different with SWT's one.

Answer (score 0):

DND does not work the way you think it does.

Consider **downloading some file from web**. 
When you **validate downloading**, there is **no actual file content** but you have the **only URL** of a web resource.

Likewise, when you validate drop operation, you can't know the actual data, because there is **no established connection** until you accept the drop operation. The only thing you can know in the validating phase is the **kind of transfer type**.

So you can only validate the drop based on the content kind, not the "Actual Content"

Typical Validation codes are:

```
public boolean validateDrop(...){
    return FileTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(transferData);
}
```

After you accept "TransferData", the transfer will retrieve the actual data from the connection.

So remember, "TransferData" is different from the actual data.

The `FileTransfer` retrieves the files in the forma of a `String` array which contains the absolute path to each file, not the Java `File` object.

P.S.: Clipboard works in the same way.

Comment: Thank's I knew all that. What are you suggesting the answer to the problem is then?

Comment: I down-voted this myself, it's a detailed piece of information for sure but it's not an answer, jeeyul has assumed that I don't understand how to use drag drop and was just expecting the file to move automatically. This isn't the case.